# Stream returning null even though EVERY print statement is getting printed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Stream which seems to work perfectly fine: Every print statement you see in the stream is getting printed. Also when calling `if(snapshot.hasData)` it apparently is true. But still, my stream only returns the following: `AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>>(ConnectionState.done, [], null, null)`.

What do I need to change in order to be able to access the Data in my retVal variable?

```
   Stream<List>? roomsListStream() {
    try {
      List<RoomsListModel> retVal = [];
      print("userId: $userId");
      var rooms = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("rooms")
          .where("users", arrayContains: userId)
          .orderBy("latestMessageTime", descending: true)
          .snapshots();
      print("rooms: $rooms");
      rooms.forEach((element) {
        element.docs.forEach((element) {
          print("element: $element");
          var room = element.data();
          print("room: $room");
          var roomId = room["roomId"];
          var otherUserId =
              room["users"].firstWhere((element) => element != userId);
          var lastMessage = room["latestMessage"];
          var lastMessageTime = room["latestMessageTime"];
          print("otherUserId: $otherUserId");
          getOtherUser(otherUserId).then((value) {
            print("value: $value");
            var avatar = value["photoUrl"];
            var name = value["name"];
            retVal.add(RoomsListModel(
                roomId: roomId,
                otherUserId: otherUserId,
                avatar: avatar,
                name: name,
                lastMessage: lastMessage,
                lastMessageTime: lastMessageTime));
          });
        });
      });
      return Stream.value(retVal);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }
```

Comment: see https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods - what you need is `Stream.map` method

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate on that? I don't really get where and why I would need that?

Comment: why you would need that? add `print('retval: $retval')` just before `return Stream.value(retVal` and you will see when it is called

Comment: Thanks again for the help! I added the print statement and it prints "retval: []". So basically my list is empty. But all my print statements before have values. Any idea what causes the list to be empty and how to fix that?

Comment: check when that print is called, it is called **before** any print from `rooms.forEach`

Comment: Correct!! Did not notice that. Thank you a lot! But what can I do to fix that and call it after the other steps are done?

Comment: i already answered that: return `map`  method called on `rooms` stream, something like `return rooms.map((elem) ...`

Comment: Can you please show me the adjustments to do? I tried to adjust it with Stream.map, but I cannot manage to make it work. I'm not very experienced and still new to coding, so sorry if that is a simple thing

Comment: see https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-async/Stream/map.html - it has an example of `map` usage

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var rooms = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("rooms")
  .where("users", arrayContains: userId)
  .orderBy("latestMessageTime", descending: true)
  .snapshots();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.